# Compare set of data in one table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, comparison

I've gone round in circles using JOIN and EXISTS and ISNULL. I cannot figure this out and I've gone through hundreds of threads.

Records in table **Pages** drives the output of individual retail web pages. Fields in this table determine what items are displayed:

- PageID INT
- Category VARCHAR(30)
- Colour VARCHAR(10)
- Size VARCHAR(10)
- OnSale BIT

e.g.

- PageID = 201
- Category = Shoes
- Colour = Red
- Size = Large
- OnSale = 1

I need to compare these fields against identically-named fields in **Accounts_Emails**.

- fk_AccountID INT
- Category VARCHAR(30)
- Colour VARCHAR(10)
- Size VARCHAR(10)
- OnSale BIT

This table allows users to save options for email newsletters. If they want to be sent more items similar to those on the current page, they click a button on that page.

What I need is a stored procedure that checks if that user already has the exact match of options in a Accounts_Emails record, and if not INSERT a new record with those options.

In the fields, a NULL value means ALL so I need to compare nulls. I pass in the PageID and AccountID to the procedure so I can pick up the current Pages record and limit the Accounts_Emails to the current user.

This is what I have:

```
IF NOT EXISTS
(

SELECT 1 FROM Accounts_Emails a
JOIN Pages l on l.PageID = @PageID
WHERE
a.fk_AccountID = @AccountID AND
(ISNULL(a.Category,'NULL') = ISNULL(l.Category,'NULL')) AND
(ISNULL(a.Colour,'NULL') = ISNULL(l.Colour,'NULL')) AND
(ISNULL(a.Size,'NULL') = ISNULL(l.Size,'NULL')) AND
(ISNULL(a.OnSale,'NULL') = ISNULL(l.OnSale,'NULL'))

)
```

Comment: I think it would be better and easier just to save the page id. I mean, you already have the data stored in the pages table, why store the same data twice?

Comment: Predicate expressions `a` and `b` are equal or both NULL :  `ISNULL(NULLIF(a, b), NULLIF(b, a)) IS NULL`

Comment: Would you be able to put that into my example above, please, so I can see how it works in practice?

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need to use a MERGE statement. Using Accounts_Emails as TARGET.

Plenty of great examples are online.